# Need to know the way to improve heatmap color distribution

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

We are testing the Data Visualization API with sample data. In some conditions, we are experiencing cases where the Heatmap color distribution does not correctly represent the actual temperature distribution. We would like to know how to fix these, so please let us know.

Please find the details of each condition below.

Thank you in advance for your help.

[Details of Issues and Needs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X2q7v.jpg)

[Details of the condition A＆B](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IgBr7.jpg)

[Details of Condition C](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5VM8K.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible to solve both issues by adjusting the "fall off" of the individual heatmap sources using the following options:

```js
const heatmapConfig = {
    /* The distance from the sensor that its value will affect the heatmap before dropping off. Measured in world coordinates of the current model. The default value is 160.0. */
    confidence: 50.0,
    /* A positive real number. Greater values of power parameter assign greater influence to values closest to the interpolated point. The default value is 2.0. */
    powerParameter: 2.0,
    /* The transparency level of the resulting fragment on the heatmap, ranging from 0.0 (completely transparent) to 1.0 (fully opaque). The default value is 1.0. */
    alpha: 1.0
};
dataVizExt.renderSurfaceShading('my-heatmap', 'temperature', getSensorValue, { heatmapConfig });
```

For more details, please take a look at this Stack Overflow answer: [Assistance with having multiple sensor types in APS DataViz Extensions Demo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75639205/assistance-with-having-multiple-sensor-types-in-aps-dataviz-extensions-demo/75695978#75695978).